# No repetir una String utilizando la función set de Python

Tags: python, set

Hola estoy intentando resolver una parte del siguiente ejercicio en python. No encuentro por ningún lado como solucionarlo.
El ejercicio pide lo siguiente : Crea un script que le pida al usuario una lista de países (separados por comas). Éstos se deben almacenar en una lista. No debería haber países repetidos (haz uso de set).

Se como ingresar un array y pedir los paises, y se usar la función set con una lista de números, el problema es que no se como utilizarla con una lista que tenga datos de tipo string. Solo me devuelve las letras sin repetir, alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: Sin un código que ver es difícil saber que haces mal

Comment: El problema es que no se como hacerlo, probe con esto : **a = [100]
a = input("Por favor ingrese una lista de paises separados por una coma : ")
print(a)
listaPaises = set()
listaPaises = set(a)
print(listaPaises)**

Comment: Por favor edita ru pregunta agregando ese código. Aquí en los comentarios no se ve muy bien

Comment: `print(set(input('Por favor ingrese una lista de países separados por una coma:').split(',')))`

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion es sencilla.

1. se crea el conjunto y se guarda en paises.
2. se pregunta cuantos paises se ingresaran y se guarda en cantidad_paises.
3. se solicita una entrada la misma cantidad de veces que el numero almacenado en la variable paises.
4. se guarda la entrada del input en el conjunto contenido en la variable paises  en cada iteracion.
5. finalmente se imprime el conjunto contenido en la variable paises.

```
paises = set()
cantidad_paises = int(input("Cuantos paises quiere ingresar?:"))

for i in range(cantidad_paises):
    palabra = input("ingrese un pais")
    paises.add(palabra)
    
print(paises)
```

En posteriores preguntas, recuerda adjuntar tu codigo en la publicacion.

Comment: Primero que nada, el que una solucion sea sencilla depende de la persona y sus conocimientos. Para un novato no es tan sencilla. Segundo, te recomiendo no usar variables que se llamen como algo built-in de Python, estas reemplazando la funcion original. Espero mis consejos ayuden a hacer de tu respuesta aun mas buena.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por la ayuda, ya me quedo un poco mas claro como se hace, gracias!

Comment: De que sea sencillo no es de arrogancia si no que para despejar la sensacion de confusion . Gracias por el comentario, no me percate ni sabia que iter es una built in funcion